# Crash in Cassandra-CLI

Tags: cassandra, cql

I created a table in CQLsh -3.0 and inserted values into it.

```
create table users (
    Id uuid PRIMARY KEY,
    Name varchar,
    Age int
);

insert into users(Id, Name, Age) values ('001', 'XYZ', '30');

cqlsh:usertable> select * from users;
 id                                   | age | name
--------------------------------------+-----+--------
 1381b530-1dd2-11b2-0000-242d50cf1ffd |  30 | XYZ
 13816710-1dd2-11b2-0000-242d50cf1ffd |  28 | ABC
 13818e20-1dd2-11b2-0000-242d50cf1ffd |  30 | PQR
```

However, when I attempt to insert new rows into this table from Cassandra-CLI interface, it crashes:

```
[default@unknown] use usertable;
Authenticated to keyspace: usertable
[default@usertable]
[default@usertable] set users['005']['name'] = 'MNO';
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Cannot locate cassandra.yaml
Fatal configuration error; unable to start server.  See log for stacktrace.
```

Has anyone else observed a similar behavior.? Is there some incompatibility between CQLsh 3.0 and Cassandra-CLI? Also, I see a similar result when using CQLsh spec 2.0.0!

Thanks,
VS

Comment: What version of Cassandra are you running?

Comment: I am running Apache Cassandra 1.1.3.

Comment: I recently upgraded from 1.1.5 to 1.1.6 and now the cli crashes all the time.  The 1.1.5 cli works just fine against my 1.1.6 system.

Comment: "See log for stacktrace."... and the stacktrace says?

Answer (score 0):

Your "Id" value is a uuid. Try setting uuid to a 16-byte value; column validation is stricter in newer versions of the CLI.